# Django: SQL result as dictionary

Tags: python, django

From the django documentation ( https://docs.djangoproject.com/el/2.1/topics/db/sql/ ) I'm using the function:

```
def dictfetchall(cursor):
    "Return all rows from a cursor as a dict"
    columns = [col[0] for col in cursor.description]
    return [
        dict(zip(columns, row))
        for row in cursor.fetchall()
    ]
```

together with

```
def my_custom_sql(self,sql):
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        cursor.execute(sql)
        row = dictfetchall(cursor)
    return row
```

trying in the console:

```
testen = my_custom_sql(Ausgaben,"SELECT TYP, count(*) Anzahl, sum(Summe) Summe FROM hhdata_Ausgaben group by typ")
testen
[{'Typ': 'Drogerie', 'Anzahl': 1, 'Summe': 6.0}, {'Typ': 'Essengehen', 'Anzahl': 1, 'Summe': 4.0}, {'Typ': 'Lieferant', 'Anzahl': 1, 'Summe': 50.0}, {'Typ': 'Taschengeld', 'Anzahl': 1, 'Summe': 5.0}]
type(testen)
<class 'list'>
```

The result looks like a dictionary but it is a list and I can't access the key and values in my template:

```
    {% for key,value in testen.items %}
      <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Why do you use raw SQL?

Comment: one row is dict but all is list of dicts

Comment: To be honest I feel way more comfortable using raw SQL rather then the django ORM @KaiserKatze

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a list of dictionaries, each dictionary in the list represents a row in the DB. As such, your loop should iterate over a list:

```
{% for row in testen %}
    {% for key, value in row.items %}
        <li><a href="{{key}}">{{value}}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Keep in mind that depending on the version of Python you are using, the order of the keys in each dictionary may be different.